# java.lang.NullPointerException on BigQuery.IO.Write in a streaming pipeline

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow

Getting below error on `BigQuery.IO.Write` from a streaming pipeline in dataflow sdk `2.1.0`

> java.lang.NullPointerException
>           org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.BigQueryServicesImpl$DatasetServiceImpl.insertAll(BigQueryServicesImpl.java:759)
>           org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.BigQueryServicesImpl$DatasetServiceImpl.insertAll(BigQueryServicesImpl.java:809)
>           org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.StreamingWriteFn.flushRows(StreamingWriteFn.java:126)
>           org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.StreamingWriteFn.finishBundle(StreamingWriteFn.java:96)

Java code:

```
PCollection<TableRow> tableRows = ...

    tableRows.apply("WriteToBQ",
            BigQueryIO.writeTableRows()
            .to(String.format("%1$s.%2$s",bqDataSet, bqTable))
            .withSchema(Schema.get())
            .withWriteDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.WriteDisposition.WRITE_APPEND));
```

Comment: Is any of `bqDataSet`, `bqTable`, or `Schema` null? Did you check the corresponding line number in whichever version of `BigQueryServicesImpl.java` you have to see what triggered the exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-2834 that has been fixed in Beam 2.2.0.

Comment: when I moved to `2.2.0` it started giving me a descriptive error `insert failed` and why, which was nice. I just had an invalid field in my table schema.

Comment: Just FYI, as noted in the first comment in the JIRA issue, the workaround for Apache Beam 2.1.0 is to call `withFailedInsertRetryPolicy(InsertRetryPolicy.alwaysRetry())` on the `BigQueryIO.Write` instance.